# JavaScript grabbing Image from the wrong Location

Tags: javascript, image

The code I'm using is pulling the image from here:

http://www.mywebsite.com/FILENAME/images/theimageiwant.jpg

The part I capitalized 'filename' is being added in somewhere in the code. Ie. I just want the images pulled from:

http://www.mywebsite.com/images/theimageiwant.jpg

If anyone could help out and let me know which part of the JavaScript I need to change or remove it would be really helpful. Even if you could just tell me which part is actually referring to 'filename' I'd probably be able to figure it out. Thanks in advance guys.

```
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
```

This is the .html

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','mywebsite.co.uk/images/porftfolio-main.jpg',1)">; 
<img src="mywebsite.co.uk/images/portfolio-thumb.jpg"; alt="portfolio-thumb" width="120" height="120" id="thumb1" /></a>
```

It's a gallery with one main picture, 4 smaller thumbnails beneath it which when you click - change the main picture. The code is standard DW, but Firebug is telling me bad requests are being made for images from the location which includes 'filename'.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? I don't think this javascript is the issue. Isn't this standard dreamweaver code?

Comment: see my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9991742/370103 Hopefully this should help you

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to the file as `images/blah.png` or whatever...
You need to add a forward slash in front:

from:
`"images/blah.png"`
to:
`"/images/blah.png"`

Comment: Thanks Ryan. It's got the trailing slash - it's pulling the image from www.mysite.co.uk/FILENAME/images/myimage.jpg - and I was trying to figure what is the JS that's grabbing the 'filename', as all my images are stored at root.

Answer (score 0):

From seeing your code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_swapImage('main','','mywebsite.co.uk/images/porftfolio-main.jpg',1)">; <img src="mywebsite.co.uk/images/portfolio-thumb.jpg"; alt="portfolio-thumb" width="120" height="120" id="thumb1" /></a>
```

Change `mywebsite.co.uk` to `http://mywebsite.co.uk`

This will change your links to [absolute URLs](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3) pointing to `/images/porftfolio-main.jpg` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the help Curt, the only thing is I need to use the 'mywebsite.co.uk' part in there else it doesn't find the image. Something to do with the way my .htacess is set up for stipping file extensions and adding a trailing slash. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DarrenFox I didn't realise this was for a different website images. In which case you need to add `http://` at the start or else the browser will see this as a local relative URL

Comment: yeah it's got the http:// part in there as well. found a new solution below, but not really sure how it works though.

Comment: Ok so I've found a way to stop Firebug getting the bad request.
It involves changing the var d=document ...to "var d=src" on the second line of the JavaScript code. Do you know if this is a legitimate fix?